# Assist me with understanding the reason of slow script performance

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, input, placeholder

I repeat usual script for  placeholder (jPlaceholder.js).

The reason is slow reading speed(~150 000\1000ms) and big file size (5.8kb);
The script below has a much faster reading speed (~1 950 000\1000ms) and is more lightweight(1.8kb).

The problem is that the first one runs ~32 000\1000ms, but my(script below) 525\1000ms only.

Please help me to understand why, and how to make it faster.

```js
 $.fn.placehold = function (option) {
        var opt = {
          wrapperClass: 'jvPlacehold',
          wrapperPadding: 0,
          wrapperMargin: 0,
          wrapperTop: 0,
          wrapperLeft: 0,
          counterClass: 'jvPhCounter',
          labelClass: 'jvPhLabel',
          labelPadding: '0 5px',
          labelColor: '#a9a9a9',
          labelOpacitySpeed: 300,
          holderDataName: 'placeholder',
          focusSpeed: 300,
          blurSpeed: 300
        };
        opt = $.extend({}, opt, option);
        var $el = $(this),
          $wrapper = $('<div>', {
            class: opt.wrapperClass,
            group: 'search',
            css: {
              overflow: 'hidden',
              background: $el.css('background'),
              width: $el.outerWidth(),
              height: $el.outerHeight(),
              padding: opt.wrapperPadding,
              margin: opt.wrapperMargin,
              top: opt.wrapperTop,
              left: opt.wrapperLeft,
              float: opt.wrapperFloat
            }
          }),
          $counter = $('<span>', {
            class: opt.counterClass,
            css: {
              display: 'none'
            }
          }),
          $label = $('<span>', {
            class: opt.labelClass,
            text: $el.data(opt.holderDataName),
            css: {
              padding: opt.labelPadding,
              color: opt.labelColor
            }
          });
        $el.css({
          position: 'absolute',
          background: 'none',
          left: 0
        });
        $el.after($wrapper.append($counter, $label)).appendTo($wrapper);
        $label.css('top', Math.abs($el.innerHeight() - $label.height()) / 2);
        $el.keyup(function () {
          if ($counter.text($el.val().replace(/\s/gi, '❙')).outerWidth() >= parseInt($label.css('left'))) $label.stop().animate({
            opacity: 0
          }, opt.labelOpacitySpeeed);
          else $label.stop().animate({
            opacity: 1
          }, opt.labelOpacitySpeeed);
        }).focus(function () {
          $label.stop().animate({
            left: ($el.innerWidth() - $label.outerWidth())
          }, opt.focusSpeed);
        }).blur(function () {
          if (!$el.val().length) $label.stop().animate({
            left: 0
          }, opt.blurSpeed);
        });
      };
      $('#search').placehold();
```

```css
div, span {
        position:relative;
      }
      input {
        padding:2px 5px;
        border:1px solid #a9a9a9;
      }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="search" data-placeholder="Search">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var tmp = new Date().getTime();
```

Write above, then use:

```
console.log(new Date().getTime() - tmp);
```

between codes to see how much time each part of code takes.

Comment: It would be better to use the browser's developer tools to figure out why a script is slow.